# What's the best controller to use for interactive books?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating an interactive touch book in iOS. I'd like to know what the best controller is to use for books. (e.g. UIViewController, NavigationController, etc.). I'd prefer to stay with  storyboard options.

And secondly what is the best way to handle pages? A separate ViewController for each page? a separate view for each page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [UIPageViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html)

From the docs:

> Page view controllers allow users to navigate between view controllers
> using the specified transition. Navigation can be controlled by the
> user using gestures as well as programatically.
>
> View controllers are either provided one at a time (or two at a time,
> depending upon the spine position and double-sided state) via the
> setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: method, or provided
> as-needed by the data source. Gesture-based navigation is enabled only
> when a data source is provided.
>
> To alter the behavior of this class, you should provide a data source
> and delegate. This class is not intended to be subclassed.

As for your second question, yes it is easiest to manage each page as a view controller since UIPageViewController is a container view controller and it holds an array of view controllers.